# PHP stream_socket_client with timeout on wss (ssl:// port 443) not working

Tags: php, ssl, websocket

I think I came down to a very specific PHP bug, that the timeouts set by stream_set_timeout() doesn't get obeyed, ONLY if using SSL websockets.

I am able to reproduce it with the following simple script:

```
<?php
$context = stream_context_create();
$fp = stream_socket_client ("ssl://echo.websocket.org:443",$errno,$errstr,5,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,$context);
stream_set_timeout($fp, 5);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Unable to open\n";
} else {

    //fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 5);
    $res = fread($fp, 2000);

    $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    //fclose($fp);

    if ($info['timed_out']) {
        echo 'Connection timed out!';
    } else {
        echo $res;
    }
}
```

If you switch out ssl://echo.websocket.org:443 with tcp://echo.websocket.org:80, the timeout gets triggered correctly after 5 seconds.

Is this a PHP bug or am I missing some sort of setting?

Comment: Have you enabled ssl for WS?

Comment: Yes. I believe I found that the PHP bug is actually this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61285 This appears to be fixed in PHP 5.5 but I am using PHP 5.3 and it's not easy to upgrade here. I'm hoping there is a work around on PHP 5.3.